# Does this problem have an "exact" solution?

Tags: r, algorithm, search, optimization, linear-programming

I am working with R.

Suppose you have the following data:

```
#generate data
set.seed(123)
a1 = rnorm(1000,100,10)
b1 = rnorm(1000,100,10)
c1 = rnorm(1000,5,1)
train_data = data.frame(a1,b1,c1)

#view data
         a1        b1       c1
1  94.39524  90.04201 4.488396
2  97.69823  89.60045 5.236938
3 115.58708  99.82020 4.458411
4 100.70508  98.67825 6.219228
5 101.29288  74.50657 5.174136
6 117.15065 110.40573 4.384732
```

We can visualize the data as follows:

```
#visualize data
par(mfrow=c(2,2))

plot(train_data$a1, train_data$b1, col = train_data$c1, main = "plot of a1 vs b1, points colored by c1")
hist(train_data$a1)
hist(train_data$b1)
hist(train_data$c1)
```

[image]

Here is the **Problem** :

1. From the data, only take variables "a1" and "b1" :  using **only 2 "logical conditions"**, split this data into **3 regions** (e.g. Region 1 WHERE 20 > a1 >0 AND  0< b1 < 25)
2. In each region, you want the "average value of c1" within that region to be as small as possible - but each region must have at least some minimum number of data points, e.g. 100 data points (to prevent trivial solutions)
3. **Goal** : Is it possible to determine the "boundaries" of these 3 regions that minimizes :

- the mean value of "c1" for region 1
- the mean value of "c1" for region 2
- the mean value of "c1" for region 3
- the average "mean value of c1 for all 3 regions" (i.e. `c_avg = (region1_c1_avg + region2_c1_avg + region3_c1_avg) / 3`)

In the end, for a given combination, you would find the following, e.g. (made up numbers):

- Region 1 : WHERE 20> a1 >0  AND 0 < b1 < 25 ; region1_c1_avg = 4
- Region 2 : WHERE 50> a1 >20 AND  25 < b1 < 60 ; region2_c1_avg = 2.9
- Region 3 : WHERE a1>50 AND   b1 > 60 ; region3_c1_avg = 1.9
- c_avg =  (4 + 2.9 + 1.9) / 3 = 2.93

And hope that (`region1_c1_avg, region2_c1_avg, region3_c1_avg and c_avg`) are minimized

**My Question**:

**Does this kind of problem have an "exact solution"?** The only thing I can think of is performing a "random search" that considers many different definitions of (`Region 1, Region 2 and Region 3`) and compares the corresponding values of (`region1_c1_avg, region2_c1_avg, region3_c1_avg and c_avg`), until a minimum value is found. Is this an application of linear programming or multi-objective optimization (e.g. genetic algorithm)? Has anyone worked on something like this before?

I have done a lot of research and haven't found a similar problem like this. I decided to formulate this problem as a "multi-objective constrained optimization problem", and figured out how to implement algorithms like "random search" and "genetic algorithm".

Thanks

**Note 1:** In the context of multi-objective optimization, for a given set of definitions of (`Region1, Region2 and Region3`): to collectively compare whether a set of values for (`region1_c1_avg, region2_c1_avg, region3_c1_avg and c_avg`) are satisfactory, the concept of "Pareto Optimality" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-objective_optimization#Visualization_of_the_Pareto_front) is often used to make comparisons between different sets of {(`Region1, Region2 and Region3`) and (`region1_c1_avg, region2_c1_avg, region3_c1_avg and c_avg`)}

**Note 2** : Ultimately, these 3 Regions can defined by any set of 4 numbers. If each of these 4 numbers can be between "0 and 100", and through 0.1 increments (e.g. 12, 12.1, 12.2, 12.3, etc) : this means that there exists 1000 ^ 4 = 1 e^12  possible solutions (roughly 1 trillion) to compare. There are simply far too many solutions to individually verify and compare. I am thinking that a mathematical based search/optimization problem can be used to strategically search for an optimal solution.

Comment: Questions about "general approach" aren't specific programming questions that are appropriate for Stack Overflow. if you want to discuss data analysis strategies, you should instead post somewhere like [stats.se] or [datascience.se]

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I think I didn't word my question in the best way. I just wanted to know if this kind of question (open ended search and optimization) appears often in computer programming. I also thought that this post could serve as a resource for anyone working on these kinds of problems.

Comment: When I read this my question was: why? I assume there is some goal or purpose to this exercise.

Comment: Suppose you want to identify 3 interpretable clusters in this data -"fully interpretable clusters", i.e. clusters that can be defined by strictly "logical conditions".  Most clustering algorithms would split this data into "irregular polygon shapes" that do not have clear interpretations. on the other hand, algorithms like decision trees could "carve up" this data into somewhat linear, yet still complicated/jagged shapes that might not be easily explainable. If you really wanted the clusters to be fully interpretable (and meet some threshold, i.e. avg-c), you might need this kind of approach.

Comment: The word clustering does not appear in the question.

Comment: I used the word "cluster" very loosely. I think this problem is more closely related to linear programming and optimization. How to choose boundaries that minimize some quantity, relative to some constraints.

Comment: Btw, I really like your blog! http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/?m=1 , especially the parts on scheduling and linear programming. The post on "largest rectangle within a histogram" was quite interesting!